# ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'app:main'

Tags: ckan

When I am running the following command at the root of my CKAN installation on a development machine:

```
paster celeryd
```

I am getting the following error.

```
File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/celery_app.py", line 29, in <module>
    sqlalchemy_url = config.get('app:main', 'sqlalchemy.url')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 607, in get
    raise NoSectionError(section)
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'app:main'
```

I checked my development.ini file and it has an `app:main` section. Not sure how to resolve this error.

Comment: I did solve this error. It was not finding the development.ini file. I created a link in the ckan source dir pointing to development.ini file and it resolved this error.

Comment: user1380140 As you solved your problem, could you either add an answer and accept it, or close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did solve this error. It was not finding the `development.ini` file. I created a link in the ckan source dir pointing to `development.ini` file and it resolved this error.